# Evaluate $\int \frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+4)} \, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

**Exercise** Evaluate $\int \frac{z^2+1}{z(z^2+4)} \, dz$ on the regions $|z|<2$ and $|z|>2$

I know that $\int_C f(z) \, dz = 2\pi i$ Res$_{z=0} \Big[ \frac{1}{z^2} f\Big( \frac{1}{z} \Big) \Big]$

So maybe we consider

$$2\pi i \, \cdot \, \, Res_{z=0} \frac{\frac{1}{z^2}+1}{z^3(z^2+4)}?$$

How can I go from here? It's not obvious to me how to find the residue of this function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not integral over a contour $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\frac{\frac1{z^2}+1}{z^3(z^2+4)}=\frac{z^2+1}{4z^5}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{z^2}4}=\frac{z^2+1}{4z^5}\left(1-\frac{z^2}4+\frac{z^4}{16}-\ldots\right)$$

Now, you only need the coefficient $\;c_{-1}\;$ of $\;z^{-1}\;$ in the above Laurent series ...

Comment: I see. But I don't observe any  $c_nz^{-n}$ terms, i.e. I don't observe any $\frac{c_n}{z^n}$ terms, so how can I possibly find $c_{-1}$?

Comment: This can be simplified to $(z^2 + 1)(z^{-5}/4 - z^{-3}/16 + z^{-1}/64 - \cdots)$. Then $z^2 \cdot (- z^{-3}/16) + 1 \cdot (z^{-1}/64)$ gives us a $c_{-1} = -3/64$.

Comment: @cheesefoot Open up parentheses. This is a hint, not the whole thing solved.